# Signal handling in docker+bash not working as expected

Tags: bash, docker, containers, posix, tini

I hit a signal handling problem, with this being the smallest reproducible example scenario.

Docker image with `tini` installed and the following final layers:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "-vv", "--"]
CMD /bin/bash
```

Bash script with traps:

```
 cat script.sh                                                                                                                                                       Wed Jun  7 18:04:53 2023
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -o pipefail

_term() {
  echo "_term(): Received $1"
  sleep 60
}

echo "Trapping signals..."

trap "_term SIGTERM" SIGTERM

sleep 900
```

This is the execution result. In one window I launch the bash script from docker, in the other I'm sending signals to the container:

```
 docker run -it c /working_dir/script.sh                                                                                                                             Wed Jun  7 17:55:24 2023
[INFO  tini (1)] Spawned child process '/working_dir/script.sh' with pid '7'
Trapping signals...
[DEBUG tini (1)] Passing signal: 'Terminated'
```

and:

```
docker kill -s 15 <container id>
```

`_trap()` code is not executed. Why is that?

Comment: The shell form of `CMD` wraps the command string in an `sh -c` invocation; is that actually receiving the signal?

Comment: Well spotted. That solved it. Feel free to turn your comment into a proper answer, I'll happily accept it.